# Xcode NSUserDefaultValues - wrong value returned

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have a strange  case of using NSUserDefaults.  I set the values in one class and retrieve them in another.

When I retrieve, 'nil' is returned to the app - and that sounded suspicious.

Has anyone run into this?  What is the solution?

```
NSUserDefaults *appPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:kFormattedDateStr];
NSLog(@"%@", [appPreferences dictionaryRepresentation]);
NSLog(@"startDateString =<%@>", [appPreferences stringForKey:kStartDateKey]);
NSLog(@"targetDateString=<%@>", [appPreferences stringForKey:kTargetDateKey]);
NSDate *targetDate = [df dateFromString:[appPreferences stringForKey:kTargetDateKey]];
[df release], df = nil;
```

I have double-checked that I am saving an retrieving the values w/ the same key. Can it be because I am saving the value as "objectForKey"   and   retrieving it as "stringForKey" ??

So, I dumped the NSUserDefaults - and it shows the values I set. I am confused as to why the code would return nil!

```
    WebKitWebArchiveDebugModeEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitWebGLEnabled = 0;
    WebKitWebSecurityEnabled = 1;
    WebKitXSSAuditorEnabled = 1;
    WebKitZoomsTextOnly = 1;
    notificationKey = 0;
    selectedGoalKey = "New Goal";
    startDateKey = "2011-06-12 15:00:51 +0000";
    targetDateKey = "2011-06-13 15:00:51 +0000";
}
2011-06-12 07:22:14.634 GoalBuggerPro[10304:207] startDateString =<(null)>
2011-06-12 07:22:20.886 GoalBuggerPro[10304:207] targetDateString=<(null)>
```

Sam.

Comment: Try calling `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` just after having stored your values.

Comment: Sorry. Where do you set the value to user defaults?

Comment: They are set by two separate methods in a different class. `code` NSDate *selected  = [[self myDatePicker]  date];
 [appPreferences setObject:selected forKey:kStartDateKey];
 [appPreferences synchronize];`code`  <<<< This is one code fragment.  The other is similar

Comment: And does kStartDateKey actually contain the key you expect ("startDateKey")? Same for kTargetDateKey.

Comment: Yes - the constant is defined as #define kTargetDateKey       @"targetDateKey"

Comment: Could you edit the question and post the code you’re using to store values in `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was what I was thinking.....

I was storing the value as an object and retrieving it as string.

After changing the code to use "objectForKey", right value was accessible.